# Why is `@messages` not used?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

The following is from [*The Rspec Book*](http://pragprog.com/book/achbd/the-rspec-book). I am wondering why `messages << message` in `def puts` is not `@messages << message`. I understand that `||= []` is memoization, and also I understand that `@messages` is an instance variable. So then, should it be used in the same class? Or is it a typo?

```
class Output
  def messages
    @messages ||= []
  end

  def puts(message)
    messages << message
  end
end

def output
  @output ||= Output.new
end

Given /^I am not yet playing$/ do
end

When /^I start a new game$/ do
  game = Codebreaker::Game.new(output)
  game.start
end

Then /^I should see "([^"]*)"$/ do |message|
  output.messages.should include(message)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for -1 guys, very encouraging. Please explain why I got -1?

Comment: the questions seems alright to me +1 :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your confusion is between `@messages` variable and `messages` method

```
class Output
  def messages
    @messages ||= []
  end

  def puts(message)
    messages << message #=> here `messages` refer to the method above
  end
end
```

Here is a simple example

```
class Output
  def m
    @messages ||= []
  end

  def puts(message)
    m << message #=> method `m`
  end
end

v = Output.new
v.puts "blah"
v.m #=> ["blah"]
```

Example 2 (for even more clarity)

```
class Output
  def m
    @messages ||= []
  end

  def puts(message)
    m << message #=> here `m` refer to the method above
  end

  def show_at_messages_variable
    @messages
  end
end

v = Output.new
v.puts "blah"
v.show_at_messages_variable #=> ["blah"]
```

Answer (score 5):

Because

```
def puts(message)
  messages << message
end
```

then calls

```
def messages
  @messages ||= []
end
```

the `||= []` assigns an empty array to `@messages` if it doesn't already exist.  That's why `puts(message)` doesn't use `@messages` directly.

Edit:
If you do `@messages << message` directly, `@messages` might not yet exist at that point.  That's why you go through `messages` instead.

Comment: Can you explain a bit about why puts(message) doesn't use part, please?

Answer (score 5):

The author opted for lazy object creation,
messages are not created in the constructor but in the getter method instead.
As long as you do not access @messages directly you can not get a nil exception.

```
class Output
  def messages
    @messages ||= []
  end

  def puts(message)
    # If i was to use the variable @messages at this point,
    # i would get a nil exception, the array was never allocated.
    # Using the getter ensures that the array is allocated.
    messages << message
  end
end
```

If you have a distinct need not to be lazy creating your objects, you could write the same class in the following manner.

```
class Output
  attr_reader :messages

  def initialize(message)
    @messages = []
  end

  def puts(message)
    # messages was created when this object was initialized,
    # thus it is perfectly safe to use here.
    @messages << message
  end
end
```